# oracle delete data from table with rownum

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that deletes the data from table1. Five instances of the procedure running the same time and all ran without any error/exception.
But still, there are many records in the table1 where EndTime <= v_purgedate. Please help.

```
declare
 rowcount1 NUMBER;
begin
    LOOP
        delete table1 eh
            where eh.EndTime <= v_purgedate
            and rownum <= 30000 ;
        rowcount1 := rowcount1 + sql%rowcount;      
        commit;
        exit when rowcount1=0;
rowcount1=0;
    END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Comment: `ROWNUM` is a pseduocolumn generated at runtime and doesn't indicate the "row count" in the table.Why do you want a batch delete? A simple delete statement (only one) should suffice.

Comment: `rowcount1=0` compares 2 values, `rowcount1 := 0` assigns a value, doenst it? If that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do what is called "do it yourself parallelism", as opposed to the parallel processing that Oracle can do by itself if you ask nicely.

There is a package called DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE that does this for you. You split the data into chunks (based on ROWIDs or numbers), then call the RUN_TASK procedure to process each chunk, either serially or in parallel. There is one commit per chunk.

Here is a demonstration that deletes 30,000 rows per commit. First, test data:

```
SQL> create table table1(endtime) as
  2  select trunc(sysdate) - level/24 from dual
  3  connect by level <= 240000;

Table TABLE1 created.

SQL> insert into table1 select * from table1;

240,000 rows inserted.

SQL> insert into table1 select * from table1;

480,000 rows inserted.

SQL> insert into table1 select * from table1;

960,000 rows inserted.

SQL> select count(*) from table1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1920000
```

Now, here is the code:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_task_name varchar2(128) := 'Delete_TABLE1';
  3    l_sql_chunk clob := q'§
  4  select date '2100-01-01' - min(endtime) start_id,
  5    date '2100-01-01' - max(endtime) end_id,
  6    chunk
  7  from (
  8    select endtime,
  9      ceil(row_number() over(order by endtime) / 30000) chunk
 10    from table1 where endtime < sysdate - 8000
 11  )
 12  group by chunk
 13  §';
 14    l_sql_run clob := q'§
 15  delete from table1
 16  where endtime between
 17    date '2100-01-01' - :start_id and
 18    date '2100-01-01' - :end_id
 19  §';
 20    l_boolean boolean := false;
 21    task_not_found EXCEPTION;
 22    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(task_not_found, -29498);
 23  begin
 24    begin
 25      DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK (l_task_name);
 26    exception when task_not_found then null;
 27    end;
 28    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_TASK (l_task_name);
 29    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL (
 30      task_name => l_task_name,
 31      sql_stmt => l_sql_chunk,
 32      by_rowid => l_boolean
 33    );
 34    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK (
 35      task_name => l_task_name,
 36      sql_stmt => l_sql_run,
 37      language_flag => 1,
 38      parallel_level => 0 -- 0 for serial, 2+ for parallel
 39    );
 40  end;
 41  /
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an endless Loop, because `rowcount1` will never be 0 when your table contains data that will be deleted.

i think what you what is

```
declare
  rowcount1 NUMBER;
begin


    LOOP
        delete table1 eh
            where eh.EndTime <= v_purgedate -- you should also initialize a variable
            and rownum <= 30000 ;
        --rowcount1 := rowcount1 + sql%rowcount;      
        commit;
        exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
rowcount1=0;
    END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the variable rowcount1, you do not assign any number to it, so its value is NULL. Afterwards, when you add a number to NULL the result is always NULL. This is surely not what you want. To illustrate:

```
SQL> declare
  2    rowcount1 NUMBER;
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('<'||rowcount1||'>');
  5    rowcount1 := rowcount1 + 1;  
  6    dbms_output.put_line('<'||rowcount1||'>');
  7  end;
  8  /
<>
<>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It seems your code will go in an endless loop. You say that is not the case, so clearly you are not showing us any real code.

Anyway, this is not a good way to do what you want. I'll post another answer saying why.

Regards, Stew Ashton

Answer (score 0):

It's a easy code for delete data in a table .
Try it.

```
    declare 
cursor c is 
select * from table1 where rownum<=30000;

begin
     for i in c loop
delete from table1 where EndTime <= v_purgedate;
       end loop;
commit;

end;
```